# Incoherence and errors in past revelations

Tags: quran, bible

Has the Quran cleared all the incoherence and errors in the bible, if this is the case, can it be used gather those items of informations which does not contradict the Quran ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you cannot say that Quran has corrected all the errors in bible, Quran is a separate book and bible of the time when Quran was revealed was corrupted, but muslims do agree it was not VERY corrupted. We cannot compare that time's bible with today's bible. So, i don't know how quran would have corrected anything which was corrupted after its revelation though.

Being said that, as we all know, Islam has always been the religion of Allah, it's just how people transformed it and changed their books and their meanings. So, w can take anything from christians/jews or in this case form bible, which has no contradiction with islam. But if we find even a slight contradiction, we will leave that thing.

Comment: "We cannot compare that time's bible with today's bible." This is wrong, there is an edition of the bible from 400 CE surviving, even available online (codex sinaiticus, see [here](http://www.codexsinaiticus.org)) which includes a complete edition of the New Testament, which is what is usually considered to be reports about the injeel - or maybe the injeel itself, I'm not sure.

Comment: Alright, this is possible, but i was talking about the today's bibles which are revised even today, and their are new and new revisions day by day.

Comment: "and their are new and new revisions day by day" I don't understand, evidence?

Comment: Day by day might not be true, what i meant was their are many versions of bible and still it is being edited and updated... Point i am trying to make is that we cannot take today's bible as words of God, and hence can't can't be sure about it. The link you gave tells about a bible which is found nd is being translated and collected... It does not mean that it was presevred and was used for 1600 years

Comment: "and still it is being edited and updated..." Evidence?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_Standard_Version have a look on the list